# Screen Button on iPad with code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, button, screenshot

I am trying to make a button that will allow me to screenshot my image on an iPad, then attach it to an e-mail. I am not developing an app, so I cannot use Objective C or UI code. I was hoping there was a way to this with Javascript or JQuery.

Basically I made a widget that you can draw in for an iBook. I want to add a button that when pressed will take a screenshot of the iPad Canvas, then attach it into an e-mail.

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find three way to take a screenshot of the browser's viewport using jQuery:
http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/08/take-webpage-screenshot-html5-jquery-javascript.html

Comment: I;ve looked at this before. I'm just not sure to add this to my code and make it function. I want to link it to a button so when the button is tapped, the screenshot is taken.